# Create event grid topic and subscription dynamically without going to azure portal by coding?

Tags: azure, azure-eventgrid

I want to create event grid topic dynamically. Whenever my azure function is triggered, it will create new topic based on input it gets. I just want to know **if there is any way I can create azure topic without going to azure portal.**

Comment: you can use for example the REST APIs, see more details in the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventgrid/

Comment: Thanks. This is what I looking for.

Comment: Note, that the AEG has a limit for number of custom topics such as 100. I do recommend to create an event domain topics, where the limit is 100,000 per event domain.

Comment: Yes I know that. Thanks for sharing. Can you know answer this question please if you know how to do it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59083546/how-to-create-event-grid-domain-topic-subscription-using-rest-api

Comment: See my answer for that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@Roman Kiss](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8084828/roman-kiss) answer:  REST APIs, see more details in the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventgrid/. You can create event topic by calling microsoft rest api.

Comment: link is issuing a 404

Comment: got an http 404 for both url :(

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventgrid/   Here is the latest link.

I don't know why Microsoft keep updating their rest api links.

Answer (score 5):

There is an EventGrid management library [Microsoft.Azure.Management.EventGrid](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.EventGrid) ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/eventgrid)) for .NET that you could use.

Comment: That's not what I am looking for. I know how to publish and consume event. I posted answer below.

Comment: The library I've linked to is **not** for publishing and subscribing. It's designed for _management_ operations. Not the same as `Microsoft.Azure.EventGrid`, which is used to publish events.