# Domain Topic and Event Subscription using java sdk

Tags: azure-eventgrid, azure-java-sdk

I have seen many examples for creating a domain topic and event subscription using rest API's but I want to create it using the azure java sdk which is already there. any leads would greatly help. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Prerequisites to create Domain Topic and Event Subscription using java SDK

- JDK with version 8 or above
- Azure subscription
- Event Grid Topic or Domain
  Following steps for creating a Topic & Domain (Azure CLI)

```sh
#create Topic
az eventgrid topic create --location <location> --resource-group <your-resource-group-name> --name <your-resource-name>
```

```sh
#create Domain
az eventgrid domain create --location <location> --resource-group <your-resource-group-name> --name <your-resource-name>
```

#### Include the Required Packages

#### Add BOM file:

Include the **azure-sdk-bom** to your project to take a dependency on GA version of the Library.

```xml
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-sdk-bom</artifactId>
            <version>{bom_version_to_target}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

And add the direct dependency in the dependencies section without the version flag

```xml
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-messaging-eventgrid</artifactId>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

#### Authenticate the Client

The authentication can be either a **key credential,** a **shared access signature**, or **Azure Active Directory token** authentication. Refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/messaging-eventgrid-readme?view=azure-java-stable#authenticate-the-client)

#### Create the client

#### Using endpoint and Access key to create the client

```java
// For custom event
EventGridPublisherAsyncClient<BinaryData> customEventAsyncClient = new EventGridPublisherClientBuilder()
    .endpoint("<endpoint of your event grid topic/domain that accepts custom event schema>")
    .credential(new AzureKeyCredential("<key for the endpoint>"))
    .buildCustomEventPublisherAsyncClient();
```

#### Using endpoint and SAS token to create the client

```java
EventGridPublisherAsyncClient<CloudEvent> cloudEventAsyncClient = new EventGridPublisherClientBuilder()
    .endpoint("<endpoint of your event grid topic/domain that accepts CloudEvent schema>")
    .credential(new AzureSasCredential("<sas token that can access the endpoint>"))
    .buildCloudEventPublisherAsyncClient();
```

Refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/messaging-eventgrid-readme?view=azure-java-stable) for more information

Comment: DelliganeshS-MT thanks for the answer. Is there any way where we can create topic and event subscription itself with java sdk? because the above one uses azure cli but I want to create it using the java sdk available.

Comment: For creating topic and event subscriptions with java SDK we need to use Rest API. Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59084329/15997690)